# How To Submit Data to Another Website to Retrieve Data

Tags: javascript, node.js

Like the title says. How can I submit data to another website to retrieve data?
I'm using Node.js.
For example, I want to go to google.com, and write "stackoverflow" to search area and hit the button. Then receive the results. How can I do this?

Comment: That doesn't happen. You simply have no control to another site unless you embed some script into it

Comment: If the targeted website has got an API, the simplest would be to consume this API. Otherwise it will depends on the website. In the case of Google you can request https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Selenium](https://selenium.dev/)

I have use it with java and python before. Here is a link that uses NodeJS: [Selenium and NodeJS](https://team.goodeggs.com/getting-started-with-selenium-webdriver-for-node-js-f262a00c52e1)